# Qt Application Customization

Tags: qt4

How to make Qt app look in Adobe Lightroom style?

Is it skin or css style?

Or maybe some other UI framework is used in Lightroom?

I want to create some form with "Video Timeline" custom widget, like in Adobe Flash, and in Lightroom style but I'm not sure from what to start, especially with "timeline widget".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/style-reference.html

or

http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/stylesheet.html

Comment: I know there are some skin libs, like in VLC also, but style solution is the only one I know is out there for sure.